# Rider line break before every Member Access Expression C#

Tags: c#, formatting, rider

I use JetBrains Rider to format my code. There is one formatting option I cannot find in the documentation: Using Entity Framework I wish to have all Queryable Extension Methods on separate lines. But the first Method always stays on the same line as the DbSet.

What I get:

```
var myVar = await testContext.TestData.Include(x => x.Collection)
      .Where(x => x.TestProperty == "Test")
      .FirstOrDefaultAsync();`
```

What I wish for:

```
var myVar = await testContext.TestData
      .Include(x => x.Collection)
      .Where(x => x.TestProperty == "Test")
      .FirstOrDefaultAsync();`
```

What I tried:

- Every option in Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> C# -> Line Breaks and Wrapping (especially under "Arrangement of Member Access Expression")
- Rider code format documentation
- Google

Comment: Have you tried the Detect Code Style Settings using an example block of code? If Rider doesn't pick up on the methods getting newlined, then it possibly doesn't have a code formatting rule built in for that specifically.